# Proving that $2^{2018}-2^{2016}+2^{2013}$ is divisible by $5$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

> Prove that $2^{2018}-2^{2016}+2^{2013}$ is divisible by $5$.

I'm not sure how do I even start, so may I get help please?

Comment: You mention in a comment to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3641562/409) that "I must not use mod". Information about what you can and cannot use should be included in the body of your question, so that people don't waste time (theirs or yours) on solutions beyond the intended scope of the problem. Also, even when you don't know how to start, you can —and should— provide context to the problem. For instance, if this is a textbook exercise, what specific results were discussed in the current or preceding chapters that you think might be helpful here? etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply factorise:

$2^{2018}-2^{2016}+2^{2013}=2^{2013}(2^5-2^3+1)=2^{2013}(25)$

Clearly $5 \mid 25$, so you are done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$2^2\equiv -1\mod 5$$
so, raise it to suitable powers to conclude the result.

Comment: I must not use mod.

Comment: You might also use $$a-b|a^n-b^n$$which yields $$5=4-(-1)|4^n-(-1)^n$$which is essentially the same of the answer.